# applu node module SCSS files only to specific page in Angular 7

Tags: css, angular, sass

I am working on creating a page with dark mode which has completely different CSS. If I add its CSS files in `angular.json` under styles

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-select-dt/css/select.dataTables.css",
          "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
          "src/assets/scss/black-dashboard.scss"
        ],
```

but this is impacting other pages since CSS adding globally and not to a single page as required.

If I want to import it in `.ts` file, I am not getting how do I link to `src` folder from any `component.ts` file.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.Component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.Component.css', '../../..src/assets/scss/black-dashboard.scss']
})
```

please help me to know how to add a `SCSS` group of files at component level `*.component.ts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start with one point,it says now u here in this folder that with two points go upfolder to src than goes to scss file.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.Component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.Component.css', './../../../src/assets/scss/black-dashboard.scss']
})
```